# How to remove the smell of Lenor Unstoppables from clothing?

Tags: cleaning, clothing, laundry

I've received a baby sleeping bag and it smells VERY strongly of [Lenor Unstoppables](http://unstopables.com/en-us/products/fresh-in-wash-scent-booster) which the previous owner liked to use. I've tried soaking it with baking soda, with vinegar, and have washed it several times. The smell has diminished but still overpowering and unbearable for me, who knows what effect this sensory overload will have on a newborn. What will be effective to remove the odour/fragrance?

Comment: Sometimes, the only way to remove a fragrance is to wash many, many times....

Comment: <rant> Tide detergent is similar. NOTHING will remove the odour. No amount of airing, washing, or neutralizing with other materials will remove these chemical contaminants. I wouldn't be surprised if the same company makes both or uses the same company for the stench. The company is "Flavours and Fragrances, Inc." based in Chicago, I think. This stuff is the AIDS of odours and stench. It never goes away. </rant>

Comment: I rented a room to a student who used Unstoppable for 2 months. It took 3 months before the smell abated and I could use the room again.
I tried everything, nothing made a bit of difference. It stank for the full 12 weeks.
I noticed that there is NOT an 800 phone number on the product.....I couldn'tcouldn't even call the company for a remedy. ... probably want to hear how many people find their smells hideous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You obviously have a strong opponent here - designed to stick to the fabric for weeks according to the manufacturer.

So pretend to "use" it:
Wash repeatedly, as hot and "rough" as the fabric will allow, air out as much as possible. Sun and wind will help break down and carry away scents.

In cases like these, I tend to leave the laundry outside even over night, e.g. wash in the morning, hang to dry outside, leave out over night (dew falling and drying again in the morning), repeat.

Expect the process to last a few days and of course *do not use detergent with (strong) scent*. Kind of obvious, but you don't want to add scent / bind the existing scent.

Comment: I had a blanket washed in that overwhelming stuff. A few days outside on a line greatly diminished the fragrance.

Comment: Tide detergent is a MAJOR offender. Avoid Tide detergent unless you want it in your possessions (clothes, containers, drawers, furniture, bags, shelves, (anything it touches) FOREVER. It is a chemical contaminant.